# can't make this (simple) recursive function return a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got the following function that I write in a factory so I can use it afterward:

```
treeView.factory('utils', function () {
    return{
        // Util for finding an object by its 'id' property among an array
        findById:function findById(a, targetId) 
        {
          var indexResult = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
          {
                //console.log(targetId + " - " +a[i].id);

                if (a[i].id === targetId)
                {

                    indexResult = i+1;  
                    console.log(a[indexResult-1]);
                    break;
                }
                else  
                {
                    if(a[i].nodes instanceof Array)
                    {
                        return findById(a[i].nodes, targetId);
                    }
                }
          }
          if(indexResult == 0)
          {

          }
          else
          {
            return a[indexResult-1]; 
          }

        }
    };

});
```

Then in my controller I call it like that:

```
$scope.elementToEdit = utils.findById($scope.data,$stateParams.elementId);
console.log($scope.elementToEdit)
```

and my console logs "found" but the return is "undefined"!

Do I call the factory the wrong way ? It doesn't seem so because I wrote it outside angular and it's the same. Or is it just too late and I can't see the obvious ?

**edit: actually the issue has nothing to do with angular. My data set isn't a simple array but an array of array, each array containing its children. I believe the function doesn't work properly because even when the functions finds the right elements it continues to run on other array of the same depth. I could do the trick with a global variable. But isn't it another way ?**

find the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/7njyuzxc/

final edit: my error was that in JS when you do a recursive function you have to call it with return like this:
return findById(a[i].nodes, targetId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error here was that in javascript when you do a recursive function you have to call it to return, like this:

```
function findbyid($array)
{
    //whatever code

    if(//conditon)
    {
    return findbyid($array)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `return` in a loop. use `break` to exit the loop and then return immediately after that

```js
var ii = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  //console.log(targetId + " - " +a[i].id);

  if (a[i].id === targetId) {
    console.log("found");
    ii = i + 1;
    break;
  } else {
    if (a[i].nodes instanceof Array) {
      findById(a[i].nodes, targetId);
    }
  }
}
if(ii == 0)
  return 1;
else
  return a[ii - 1];
```

Comment: well thanks I didn't know that. I updated my code: I still get only 1, although the success is logged in the console. It's not my night.

Comment: @Eagle1 Have you modified your code to look like mine? The code I've posted should work out of the box :)

Comment: yes I did, look at it, everything is the same but the variable name

Comment: I added a fiddle with my data set. I would like to solve it without using a global variable. is it possible ?